# Python | AWS : unable to write file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am fetching data from api and trying to write it in a file, when I run script on local system it works fine but same script is unable to run on ec2 instance.

```
req = requests.get(f"https:api_url", stream=True)
    with open(dataHandle+'.pb','wb') as handle: 
        for block in req.iter_content(1024):
            handle.write(block)
```

EC2-instance is not showing any error but when I debugged the execution got stop on above line code.

I tried:

To run script from root using : `sudo su -` didn't work

Tried to change the permission of folder:

```
ls -ald /var/www

chown -R root:root /home/ec2-user/scrips/api
```

didn't work

Can anyone guide me on how to write file on ec2 instance using python?

FYI: My AWS OS is CENTOS

My python script is in dir `/home/ec2-user/scrips/api`

Comment: Can you write to the destination file outside of Python? e.g. `echo test > /path/to/file`

Comment: @KlausD. I've upadted the question, my script is in dir `/home/ec2-user/scrips/api`

Comment: But you did not answer my question.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry, I didn't understand. I'm new to linux and aws, I tried to rrun as you shown example  `echo test > /home/ec2-user/scrips/api/get_data.py` but didn't get any output

Comment: @ShinChan: Does your EC2 instance have internet access or the URL from which you are trying to fetch the data is accessible from the EC2 instance? You can check using `curl -I www.google.com` or `wget your_url`

Comment: @HarshBafna My ec2 instance have internet access because I have another script which also fetch data from api, the difference here is I am not able to write the data in file

Comment: @ShinChan: What's the EC2 instance type and the configured disk space? Also as recommended by @Klaus D.  please check if this command works fine: `echo test > /home/ec2-user/scrips/api/test.txt`. You will need to run this command using the root user as you have changed the ownership of the directory to root.